# Pandas Multi-index slice only on secondary index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following pandas (related to the example here: [pandas: slice a MultiIndex by range of secondary index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389203/pandas-slice-a-multiindex-by-range-of-secondary-index))

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

variable = np.repeat(['a','b','c'], [5,5,5])
time = [0,1,5,10,20,0,1,5,10,20,0,1,5,10,20]

arra = [variable, time]

index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arra, names=("variable", "time"))

s = pd.Series(
    np.random.randn(len(sequence)), 
    index=index
)
```

Output would be

```
# In [1]: s
variable  time
a         0      -1.284692
          1      -0.313895
          5      -0.980222
          10     -1.452306
          20     -0.423921
b         0       0.248625
          1       0.183721
          5      -0.733377
          10      1.562653
          20     -1.092559
c         0       0.061172
          1       0.133960
          5       0.765271
          10     -0.648834
          20      0.147158
dtype: float64
```

If I slice here on both multiindex, it would work like this:

```
# In [2]: s.loc[("a",0),:]
variable  time
a         0       1.583589
          1      -1.081401
          5      -0.497904
          10      0.352880
          20     -0.179062
dtype: float64
```

But how can I just slice on secondary index "time" at e.g. time=0 and get every row with first index? The following won't work:

```
# In [3]: s.loc[(0),:]

KeyError: 0
```

How would I do that here?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Python Pandas slice multiindex by second level index (or any other level)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33194016/2662901)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with specify second level or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html) with `:` for select all values of first level and `0` for select values of second level:

```
print (s.xs(0, level=1))
```

Or:

```
print (s.loc[:, 0])


a    0.376784
b   -0.643836
c   -0.440340
dtype: float64
```

If working with indices and column(s) of DataFrame use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = pd.concat([s,s * 10], axis=1, keys=['a','b'])
print (df)
                      a          b
variable time                     
a        0     1.054582  10.545820
         1    -1.716213 -17.162130
         5    -0.187765  -1.877645
         10   -0.419005  -4.190047
         20   -0.772808  -7.728078
b        0    -0.022520  -0.225202
         1    -0.638453  -6.384531
         5     0.410156   4.101559
         10    0.512189   5.121889
         20   -1.241232 -12.412322
c        0    -0.134815  -1.348148
         1    -1.007632 -10.076318
         5    -0.859790  -8.597898
         10   -0.623177  -6.231767
         20   -0.635504  -6.355036

print (df.loc[idx[:, 0], 'a'])
variable  time
a         0       1.054582
b         0      -0.022520
c         0      -0.134815
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great. ".xs" works now, I am currently trying the solution with my real dataframe, but I want to select/keep all columns instead of "a". Leaving only the comma results in "
UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'"

Comment: Yes, then need `df = df.sort_index()` first.

Comment: In docs it is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex)

Comment: Can I ask a very related question to the same example here, or do I need a new question

Comment: I am offline now, on phone only, so better new question.

Comment: ok, done. was a misinterpretation on my side. everything fine now. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggested by jezrael is neat and works.
As an alternative approach you could use [swaplevel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) like this:

```py
print(s.swaplevel().loc[0, :])

variable
a    1.534837
b    1.311133
c    0.215539
dtype: float64
```