# Retrieve columns from pandas MultiIndex with multiple slices

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have a dataframe with MultiIndex columns (2 levels) and the labels of the second levels are not the same for the different groups of the first column. Consider this example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3),
                   columns=list('abc'))
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((["df1"], df1.columns))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100, 112).reshape(4, 3),
                   columns=list('def'))
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((["df2"], df2.columns))
df = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)
```

It looks something like this

```
    df1         df2
    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   0   1   2   100 101 102
1   3   4   5   103 104 105
2   6   7   8   106 107 108
3   9   10  11  109 110 111
```

Now I would like to find a simple way to retrieve one **or more** columns of the first and the second group. I.e. something like

```
    df1     df2
    a   b   d
0   0   1   100
1   3   4   103
2   6   7   106
3   9   10  109
```

However, whatever I try, doesn't work.
For example,

```
df.loc[:, [('df1', 'a'), ('df2', ['d', 'e'])]]
```

throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. The same is true for

```
df.loc[:, [pd.IndexSlice['df1', 'a'], pd.IndexSlice['df2', ['d', 'e']]]]
```

Is there a way of selecting these columns without using `pd.concat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to [Python Pandas slice multiindex by second level index (or any other level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194016/python-pandas-slice-multiindex-by-second-level-index-or-any-other-level)

Then `df.loc[:, (slice(None), ('a', 'b', 'd'))]` should give the expected result.

Comment: This is a great answer. However, I just realised that I have worded the question in a wrong way. I would also like to be able to take all columns of the first group and a subset of the second. I will ask another one.

Comment: @zeawoas - su list of tuples is not possible?

Comment: @jezrael it is possible, but my actual use case is a lot more complicated and I would like to query the dataframe programmatically. For this, this is a better solution. I still upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of tuples as :
`df.loc[:,[('df1', 'a'),('df1', 'b'),('df2','d')]`